# Raspberry Pi DC motor control with position feedback

Tags: motor, dc-motor, raspberry-pi, brushless-dc-motor

I'm interested in controlling a DC motor using a Raspberry Pi and I want to know the approximate position of the motor.

I have seen multiple ESC for sale but most don't appear to provide any feedback, they are at best open loop with the Pi providing the targeted speed and the controller doing its best to keep up.

I'm interested in both brushed and brushless solutions but for my immediate application it would be brushed.

What are some solution? Can the PI handle sampling an encoder directly? I did come across one controller but its price was well outside my range.

Thanks

Comment: https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.14.38.719b4f55zkkbc5&id=608008453111&ns=1&abbucket=13#detail

Comment: https://www.pololu.com/category/157/encoders-for-micro-metal-gearmotors

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/510755/help-with-choice-of-dc-motor-speed-control-pwm-vs-regulator/510834#510834

Comment: https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=568690950220