# Parallel MOSFET and H-Bridge

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, h-bridge, powermosfet

I need to control a 12V 100A DC motor and I was thinking of using this circuit, I saw many post and application notes that talk about parallelizing MOSFETs but I did not see any circuit using MOSFET drivers or in H-Bridge, my question is if this circuit is ok

BTW: The mosfet that I will use are IRF1404, Rds=0.004 ohm

Edited: sorry I avoid the circuit

[image]

Comment: High side N channel ones eh?

Comment: I have been playing with BTN7971B MOSFET H-bridge driveres. I also experimented with paralleling two L298N drivers and found no problems. Of course there are many other MOSFET H-bridge drivers.  You might like to skim some of my answers below: 
(1) https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/559090/why-is-my-pwm-efficiency-about-50,
(2) https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/559986/is-it-necessary-to-use-a-pull-down-resistor-with-this-bts7960,
(3) https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/556772/anything-wrong-with-connecting-l298ns-in-parallel, / to continue, ...

Comment: / cont'd, (4) https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/510755/how-to-control-dc-motor-speed-by-motor-driver-with-pwm-input. Cheers.

Comment: I'm sure that you appreciate your motor is 1.2kW - the size of a professional circular saw. And that's what it can do. Is there any motor /voltage feedback elsewhere? Running offa what? Battery? Fuse? Can IN1 and IN2 both be the same state as that catches many  out here?

Comment: But IRF1404 can already do 200+A continuous, so there is no need to parallel two IRF1404 for bigger current.